# Failed to read or create install properties file in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

At the time of installation there was no SDK packages downloaded previously, so when I tried downloading the SDK platforms it shows errors for Android Emulator as in the below screenshot. I am using proxy internet. Please suggest a better solution. I tried taking ownership from root to myself, but it didn't worked.

[image: Error image]

Answer (score 1):

I ran the Android Studio as administrator and then it worked.
Go into the Android Studio folder and type:

```
sudo sh studio.sh
```

Comment: How to do this? How to become administrator?

Comment: I tried running android-studio from root access but still the error is same.

Comment: Try sudo sh studio.sh in folder

Comment: will you please explain the procedure?

Comment: Just go in android studio folder e type the command i write above

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to install Android Studio on a proxied internet without any errors:

1. First, download the packages from the [official site](https://developer.android.com/studio), then extract those packages in a new folder named `android`.
2. Then, create a new folder and give it the name `sdk`.
3. At the time of installation, when the setup wizard asks for the SDK folder, give this path of the SDK folder that you have created.
4. Make sure that in the SDK folder, you have a folder named "platforms" so that it will download all the platforms in that folder.

It will work smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Owner of ANDRIOD_HOME must be same as the user who is starting your Andriod Studio.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $ANDRIOD_HOME
```